# JavaFx: Listener and/or binding handling

Tags: java, javafx, binding, javafx-8, listener

I was just wondering how JavaFx handles the listeners for an `ObservableValue`.
I have a few uncleared things about the Listeners in general:

- How do javaFx handles multiple listeners on the same value? As I know I can add multiple listeners to the same obsValue, then what is the trigger order? Like in fifo?
- What happens if I add the same listener(the same instance) twice to the same object, does is gets added twice? if yes then it triggers twice? Or i'm not sure how it works.
- I know there are cases when I can replace listener with binding and vice versa, but which is more effective? Better to bind, or better to add a listener?

I am using the listeners and the bindings for a while so i know how to use them(at least I think I know :) ), then I'm not interested in how to use them, since I have to do some more complex listens or bindings I want to clarify some points like I wrote, to be sure I'm using them effectively, and I don't do any unnecessary memory leaks.

I would accept any explanations in this domain, or any good documentation, where I can find answers at leas for these points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do javaFx handles multiple listeners on the same value? As I know
>   I can add multiple listeners to the same obsValue, then what is the
>   trigger order? Like in fifo?
>
> What happens if I add the same listener(the same instance) twice to
>   the same object, does is gets added twice? if yes then it triggers
>   twice? Or i'm not sure how it works.

Let us look at the documentation for one part of the answer:

[`ObservableValue<T>.addListener(ChangeListener<? super T> listener);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener-javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener-)

> Adds a ChangeListener which will be notified whenever the value of
>   the `ObservableValue` changes.
>
> **If the same listener is added more than once, then it will be
>   notified more than once. That is, no check is made to ensure
>   uniqueness.**
>
> Note that the same actual ChangeListener instance may be safely
>   registered for different ObservableValues.

The bold section of the statement above tells us all we need to know, adding the same `ChangeListener` `n` times will cause it to be fired `n` times.

The `ObservableValue` interface does not specify any operations for checking if a `ChangeListener` already exists. You may be lucky and find an implementation does give you this mechanism, but really it is not of much use. To guarantee you are not adding a duplicate `ChangeListener` you can do the following:

```
ChangeListener<...> myListener = ...;
someProperty.removeListener(myListener);
someProperty.addListener(myListener);
```

In terms of the order executed the `ObservableValue` interface itself does not specify the order.

Looking at the standard `Property` classes included in the JavaFX library, e.g. `SimpleDoubleProperty`, they are fired off in the order added. It is difficult to explain quickly how this is achieved to the slightly complex mechanisms used by classes such as `SimpleDoubleProperty`. Look at the [`ExpressionHelper`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/binding/ExpressionHelper.java) class for more detail on how this is done.

If you were to implement the `ObservableValue` interface yourself (although this is not advised by the Javadoc) you could specify your own order of execution.

---

> I know there are cases when I can replace listener with binding and
>   vice versa, but which is more effective? Better to bind, or better to
>   add a listener?

Bindings are generally used when you want to bind `Property<T>` objects together, so for example if you bind `propertyB` to `propertyA` (i.e. `propertyA.bind(propertyB)`) then when `propertyB` is changed, `propertyA` will also change. Bindings can be bi-directional as well.

So, if you want a change to effect another `Property` using a bind makes sense. But note, that properties only reference a single other property through binding. To bind multiple properties you can daisy chain them like a link list (through their bindings) or by using a class that facilitates multiple bindings (e.g. [`DoubleBinding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleBinding.html))

If the above is not the case, add a `Listener`.

Also see this resource: [Using JavaFX Properties and Binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)

Comment: Thanks the detailed answer, for the first point, one more question: There is no way to ensure that if I added once a listener to an `ObservableValue`, then the same listener to be not added again. I mean the same instance. I don't really know what does that *Note about safely registered* means in the javadoc.

Comment: @Sunflame as to notification order: what's not specified doesn't exist ;) So either you find such a specification (in the back of my mind I thought I had seen it, but can't find it now) or you must not rely on whatever assumed (read: implemented) order. Don't understand what you mean in your comment: it's you adding listeners in your code, so you know whether you add them twice ..

Comment: Yeah, but there are cases, like an event is fired which adds a listener to a property, and from then I want to listen to that property's change, but I want to be sure if that event is fired again and I have already added the listener to my property to don't do again.

Comment: @Sunflame keep a reference to the listener and remove it before adding

Comment: @Sunflame edited the answer regarding point one. Essentially the only way to do so is to keep a reference to the listener and remove it before adding. The comment *Note that the same actual ChangeListener instance may be safely registered for different ObservableValues.*  just means you can share the `ChangeListener` with other `ObservableValue` objects.

Comment: Okay @kleopatra then I go this way, thanks for both of you :)